# Run several regressions in a function

Tags: r, linear-regression

I want to write a function that I can pass a data.table, a column in this data.table as the dependant variable and several columns as regressors.

```
create_tables <- function(DT_for_regression, DepVar, Control1, 
Control2 = NULL, Control3 = NULL)
{

 results <- felm(Depvar ~ Control1 + Control2 + Control3 | Firm +  
time | 0 | Industry, data = DT_for_regression, exactDOF = FALSE, 
na.action = na.omit)
 summary(results)
}
create_tables(DT, "Outcome", "Variable_of_interest")
```

I played around a lot, by putting "get" around the variables, by specifying the variables as a formula so on, but I always get the error message that "Outcome" (the variable name I passed to Depvar) cannot be found (even though it exists in DT_for_Regression). Does anyone have an idea? The reason I want to do this in a function is that I want to run several combinations of regressions at once and being able to change one variable just with one click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paste the formula together and then pass that to your model.

```
create_tables <- function(DT_for_regression, DepVar, Control1, 
                          Control2 = NULL, Control3 = NULL){

  my_formula <- as.formula(
    paste(DepVar, '~',
          paste(c(Control1, Control2, Control3), collapse = '+'),
          '| Firm + time | 0 | Industry')
  )

  results <- felm(my_formula, data = DT_for_regression, exactDOF = FALSE,
                  na.action = na.omit)
  summary(results)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot! I also need to put "as.formula" around the paste command, otherwise I got an environment error.